# Filter chain halted as :authenticate_active_admin_user rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am using active admin for admin portal. So before the admin user had a role called admin to access the admin portal but now the name of that role has been changed to company_admin. But after this change I am not able to access the admin portal.
When I try to access the admin portal I am redirected to the home page of the website.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  require 'sidekiq/web'

  authenticate :user, ->(u) { u.has_role?(:company_admin) } do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/admin/sidekiq'
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations', registrations: 'registrations', sessions: 'sessions', passwords: 'passwords' }
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

active_admin.rb

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
```

application_controller.rb

```
def authenticate_admin_user!
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user&.has_role?(:company_admin)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `authenticate_admin_user!` being called?

As far as I can see the only thing ActiveAdmin does in [authenticate_active_admin_user](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/74825da7af450073b766496f500379e28dd5e603/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb#L39) is to check if the auth method exists and then calls it.

In any case I think you should be using [current_active_admin_user](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/74825da7af450073b766496f500379e28dd5e603/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb#L42) instead of `current_user` in your authentication method.

Comment: in active_admin initializer I have defined

config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!

Comment: I saw that, please try calling `current_active_admin_user ` instead of `curent_user`

Comment: even if I do that I am not able to access the admin portal

Comment: Can you add more information? like is your `authenticate_admin_user!` being called? what is the value of `current_active_admin_user`, whats the value of `current_user`